# A squared $2 \times 2$ matrix that has a trace of $0$ and determinant of $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm supposed to find a $2\times 2$ matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\ 
  c & d
\end{pmatrix}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ that qualifies $Tr(A^2)=0$ and $det(A^2)=1$.

Let's say that $A^2=B$. Then if $B = \begin{pmatrix}
  i & 0\\ 
  0 & -i
\end{pmatrix}$ or $B = \begin{pmatrix}
  -i & 0\\ 
  0 & i
\end{pmatrix}$ it satisfies $Tr(B)=0$ and $det(B)=1$.

But since matrix $A$ is supposed to be over $\mathbb{R}$, so I can't use $i$ as and element of $A$, or can I?

Is there an actual answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your complex matrix is a good start: after a suitable change of basis, you can make it real
and it turns out to be a rotation matrix:
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \cos \dfrac\pi2 & \sin\dfrac\pi2 \\ -\sin\dfrac\pi2 & \cos\dfrac\pi2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Dividing the angle by 2 gives a square root:
$$ A =
\begin{pmatrix} \cos \dfrac\pi4 & \sin\dfrac\pi4 \\ -\sin\dfrac\pi4 & \cos\dfrac\pi4 \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an actual answer to this.  Take, for example,
$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}2 & 2\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $ \ \mathsf{A} \ =  \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right] \ \ ,  $ we have  $ \ \mathsf{A}^2 \ = \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a^2 \ + \ bc &  ab \ + \ bd   \\ ac \ + \ cd  & d^2 \ + \ bc \end{array} \right] \ \ . $  So
$$  Tr (\mathsf{A}^2) \ \ = \ \ a^2 \ + \ 2bc \ + \ d^2 \ \ \ \text{and} \  \ \ \det(\mathsf{A}^2) \ \ = \ \ (ad \ - \ bc)^2 \ \ . $$

If we are restricting ourselves to real-valued entries, then the only condition we really need to impose is $ \ 2bc \ = \ -(a^2 \ + \ d^2) \ $ in order to have $ \ Tr (\mathsf{A}^2) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ since we can always include a multiplier on the entries of $ \ \mathsf{A} \ $ to get $ \ \det(\mathsf{A}) \ = \ \pm1 \ $ .

So, for instance, $ \ \mathsf{A} \ = \ \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{array} \right] \ \  $  works, and so does  $ \ \mathsf{A} \ = \ \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 3 & -1 \\ 17 & -5 \end{array} \right] \ \   $ and $ \ \mathsf{A} \ = \ \pm\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}}\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 3 & -1 \\ 17 & 5 \end{array} \right] \ \ .  $